# Insert with the PDO extension

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

It seems i have a syntax error in this part. It's is driving me mad. Maybe the insert syntax is not correct ?

```
public static function saveUser($form)
{
  $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cdiscountdb", 'root', 'root'); // connexion à la BDD
  $connexion->setAttribute  (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $connexion->exec("INSERT INTO ope_tartine_nl(first_name,last_name,email,created_date,updated_date) VALUES ($form['name'],$form['lastname'],$form['email'],date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))");

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connexion->exec("INSERT INTO ope_tartine_nl(first_name,last_name,email,created_date,updated_date) VALUES ('".$form['name']."','".$form['lastname']."','".$form['email']."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'");
```

Comment: @webaware you're right, pdo allows you to prepare even the insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to embed values in a string. You should read the following:

- [PHP manual, re: "double-quoted" strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)
- [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/), or why not to do that with SQL statements
- [PHP manual, re: PDO prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Then look at this version of your code:

```
public static function saveUser($form)
{
  $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cdiscountdb", 'root', 'root'); // connexion à la BDD
  $connexion->setAttribute  (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ope_tartine_nl(first_name,last_name,email,created_date,updated_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
  $cmd = $connexion->prepare($sql);
  $result = $connexion->exec(array($form['name'], $form['lastname'], $form['email'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with Zend Framework, the ZF way to do this would be:

```
$db->insert('ope_tartine_nl', array(
    'first_name' => $form['name'],
    'last_name' => $form['lastname'],
    'email' => $form['email'],
    'created_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'updated_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
));
```

(where `$db` is a Zend_Db adapter instance)